# Convert document library word document to pdf using third party dll

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, word, pdf

Hi I want to convert word document in pdf.

I found lots of solution using office dll. But i want a solution using free third party dll because in office dll there must be office installed. so on my server there is'n office installed.

Is there any free third party dll???

Comment: [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Comment: itextsharp is used for converting html to pdf not for word to pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running SharePoint 2010 enterprise then you should use word automation services see [Convert Word Document to PDF Using SharePoint and Word Automation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff181518.aspx://)

Answer (score 1):

Not a free solution, however for the benefit of others you can use the Sharepoint range from Aspose to convert Word to PDF in Sharepoint without using word automation.